# How can I remove deleted questions from my profile on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-questions

I have asked some questions here. Now, I don't want these questions into my profile.

When I delete any of the questions, it says "undelete" but does not remove that question from my profile.

How can I delete it?

Comment: This is a meta stackoverflow question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-to-delete-closed-question

Comment: Why doesn't this question say that it was migrated except in the revision list?

Comment: @mmyers - I've noticed this a couple of times today and just posted a bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53243/migrated-questions-dont-have-the-link-back-to-the-original-any-more

Answer (score 1):

Posts and questions remain posts and questions, but with a deleted status. You don't have access to the tools to delete those. They will remain visible to you with an "undelete" option.