# Migrated questions don't have the link back to the original any more

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

This question on Super User - [Format an external hard disk to FAT32, only option showing is NTFS](https://superuser.com/questions/151184/format-an-external-hard-disk) - was migrated from Stack Overflow, but doesn't have the link back to the original question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018462/format-an-external-hard-disk-closed. The Stack Overflow question has the forward link.

This is the second time I've seen this today.

In both cases I flagged the SU question for moderator attention, but thought I ought to post a bug.

Here's one from yesterday:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005808/two-monitors-one-button-closed

[Two monitors - One Button?](https://superuser.com/questions/150614/two-monitors-one-button)

And one migrated to Server Fault:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004396/nginx-and-multiple-wordpress-instances-with-fastcgi-under-same-domain-closed

[Nginx and multiple wordpress instances with fastcgi under same domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/149638/nginx-and-multiple-wordpress-instances-with-fastcgi-under-same-domain)

Comment: An example on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53021/how-can-i-delete-the-questions-in-stackoverflow

Comment: yeah, i've noticed these too, prior to seeing your mod flags.  nothin' i can do afaik.  either a deliberate UI change or a bug.  note the original link can still be found in the question timeline and/or revision history.  (timeline just gives the URL, tho; history gives a clickable link.)

Comment: @quack - I realised that there was probably nothing a moderator could do only after flagging the second post. I thought the chances of one of the team seeing the flag would be small too, hence the bug report.

Comment: @quack Can you test something? I saw one of these questions get closed on Meta earlier, and it spawned the migrated message. Can you see what happens if you close and then reopen the migrated question?

Comment: @ccomet, @quack - if that's the case then it sounds more like a bug than "by-design".

Comment: @ccornet: already tested; yes, it shows back up when the question is closed.  @chrisf: the team does sometimes view the flags so it wasn't totally worthless.  thanks for only flagging 2, tho. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This slipped through in an optimization we made to reduce queries on the main Question Show page (i.e. this page :).

It will be fixed in tonight's deployment - thanks!

Comment: verified.  thanks for the quick fix.